# Is shared Memcache guarantees the order of a list?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, arraylist, memcached

I am putting the list of objects in the shared memcache like below.

```
List<Terminology> terminologyList = companyService.getTerminologyList();
MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
memcacheService.put("terminologyList", "terminologyList")

List<Terminology> oldTerminologyList = (List<Terminology>)memcacheService.get("terminologyList");
```

Will terminologyList  and oldTerminologyList come in the same order?

Comment: If it doesn't guarantee this it is a bug, since the `List` contract guarantees iteration order

Comment: Only sorted implementations guarantee the order in any Collection

Comment: @GermannArlington _iteration_ order. `List` guarantees this.

Comment: Hopefully the third line is actually memcacheService.put("terminologyList", terminologyList)

Comment: @fge - `List` itself guarantees the order, something that generates (new) `List` does not have to generate new `List` in the same order as the old one.

Comment: @GermannArlington and if it does not do so, it is a bug since it breaks a fundamental contract that Java guarantees. As I said in the first comment!

Comment: @fge Java guarantees the behaviour of `List` instance. You can not enforce the same order of the external changing data. If the data  was added to underlying structure between calls to `List` generator this generator can not return the same `List` (order/sequence) because the content has changed. The `List` instance returned by the generator behaves in accordance with `List` interface contract.

Comment: @GermannArlington fine, the way you make a distributed cache that does Java, tell me and I won't use it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does guarantee order.

It's actually not memcache that guarantees order, because memcache just stores a byte array. It's client side Java api that does object-to-byte-array serialization, which uses just plain [Java serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java). This guarantees that object put in is the same as object you get out.

Also, the order of objects in List is [guaranteed by specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html): `A List is an ordered Collection (sometimes called a sequence)`. So it will maintain the order of elements as they were put in.